# Remove strong tag inside hyperlink with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove the  tag inside this HTML but can't seem to work out how:

```
<p>This is his: “<u><a href="https://secure.nm.com/"><strong>Fourth and Final Prediction</strong></a></u>.”</p>
```

I've tried this but it's not working - where am I going wrong?

```
$("a:has(strong)").each(function() {
$(this).replaceWith($(this).children());
```

})

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish that.

If you want to remove all of the html you can replace the HTML with the text.

```
$(this).html($(this).text());
```

If you want to replace the HTML with everything in strong you can replace the HTML with the strong HTML:

```
  $(this).html($(this).find("strong").html())
```

```js
$("a:has(strong)").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text());
  //$(this).html($(this).find("strong").html())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is his: “<u><a href="https://secure.nm.com/"><strong>Fourth and Final Prediction</strong></a></u>.”</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) function:

```
$('a strong').contents().unwrap();
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('a strong').contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is his: “<u><a href="https://secure.nm.com/"><strong>Fourth and Final Prediction</strong></a></u>.”</p>

<p>This is his: “<u><a href="https://secure.nm.com/"><strong>Fourth and Final Prediction</strong></a></u>.”</p>

<p>This is his: “<u><a href="https://secure.nm.com/"><strong>Fourth and Final Prediction</strong></a></u>.”</p>
```

The `.unwrap()` method removes the element's parent and returns the unwrapped content.